# Defraction limits of muli-image super resolution for satellites

Tags: visible-light, diffraction, space, imaging, image-processing

Is it possible to increase the resolution of satellite imagery with multiple passes through the use if multi-image super resolution algorithms?

I would imagine that probably the optical systems are limited not by sensor resolution but by lens diffraction limits (because cost of sensors is not a problem).

However, is this really the case. And if so, can multiple images surpass this limit.

thanks :)

Comment: at lower frequencies it is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic-aperture_radar , at optical frequencies i am sure it is much tougher for one may need localization within a fraction of a wavelength for coherent combining.

Comment: Sounds like [image stacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift-and-add)